# Promise.all no return res map nodejs

Tags: node.js, async-await, outlook-restapi

We are integrating with Outlook api and we need to group the attachments in the recovered emails:

We  re trying this way:

```
const result = await client
    .api('/me/messages')
    .filter(searchMailFrom)
    .select('subject, from, receivedDateTime, sentDateTime, isRead, toRecipients, hasAttachments')
    .get()

  let dadosAnexo = result.value.map(async item => {
    if (item.hasAttachments) {
      const resultAtt = await client
        .api('/me/messages/' + item.id + '/attachments')
        .get()

      item.anexos = resultAtt.value
    }
  })

  await Promise.all(dadosAnexo)

  return res.status(200).send(result.value)
```

But when we put Promise.all (), the system simply returns nothing

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. https://jsfiddle.net/4m95j6wr/ Your code appears to work, assuming that the `.get()`s return Promises.

Answer (score -1):

You are not returning anything from inside your `.map` functions. So, `dadosAnexo` becomes an array of `Promise`s that will each resolve to `undefined`.

*Check the MDN docs for more details about how `.map` works: [Map | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).*

Then, you are passing `dadosAnexo` to your `Promise.all` call.

> But when we put Promise.all (), the system simply returns nothing

Here, your assumption is wrong.

```js
await Promise.all(dadosAnexo)
```

The `await Promise.all` call above will actually return an array of `undefined`. Because you are passing it `dadosAnexo` (an array of `Promise`s, each of which resolves to `undefined`). Also, you are not assigning the return value to any variable (so, you don't actually know if it's returning something or not).

*Check the MDN docs for more details about how `Promise.all` works: [Promise.all() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)*

Now to solve your problem, here's a solution:

```js
const result = await client
    .api('/me/messages')
    .filter(searchMailFrom)
    .select('subject, from, receivedDateTime, sentDateTime, isRead, toRecipients, hasAttachments')
    .get()

// promisesToAttach will be an array containing some Promises and some item values
const promisesToAttach = result.value.map(item => {
  if (item.hasAttachments) {
    // returning a promise
    return client
      .api('/me/messages/' + item.id + '/attachments')
      .get()
      .then(resultAtt => {
        item.anexos = resultAtt.value
        return item
      })       
  }
  // returning an item value
  return item
})

// resultWithAttachments will be an array of resolved item values
const resultWithAttachments = await Promise.all(promisesToAttach)

return res.status(200).send(resultWithAttachments)
```

Comment: Makes sense! But anyway it continued loading after the request, I gave an console at the then and the data is there

Comment: `So, dadosAnexo becomes an array of  undefined.` This is incorrect. He's using an async function, which will automatically return a Promise that resolves once all `await`s inside are complete - and that automatically-created array of Promises *sounds like* it should be what he should be calling `Promise.all` on.

Comment: @Snow yes, you are correct. I've fixed my explanation.

Comment: @ViniciusSpinellis Please edit your question about details about what you tried so far and what problem you are facing now. Include as much details as you can, be verbose.